# AngularJS execution order with `$q` -- Chaining Promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Following Approach works:

```
$q.when()
        .then(checkCookieToken)         // check if cookie already exists e.g. in cookie
        .then(setHeader)                // set Header with REST-Token e.g from cookie
        .then(checkTokenOnline)         // if not OK logout
        .then(getMenu)                  // if previous OK get navigation menu
        .then(getDataResource)          // set ngResource
        .then(getData);                 // and query it
```

**4 Questions:**

1) If e.g. `checkTokenOnline` is not OK, I don't want to execute the rest functions, how can I quit (exit, break, whatever,..) at this point?

2) How can I set some of them parallel and some of them serial ?

3) How can I transfer data between them?

4) How can I make the following function dependend from its previous result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking how to **chain** functions in promises.

> 3) How can I transfer data between them?
>
> 4) How can I make the following function depend on its previous result?

**Return** data (or a promise) for the next function in the **chain**:

```
var p2 = p1.then ( function (data) {
     var nextData = someFn(data);
     return nextData;
});

var p3 = p2.then ( function (nextData) {
     var nextData2 = someOtherFn(nextData);
     return nextData2;
});

//return for further chaining
return p3;
```

> 1) If e.g. checkTokenOnline is not OK, I don't want to execute the rest functions, how can I quit (exit, break, whatever,..) at this point?

To **reject** a promise, have your function **throw** an error. The chain will skip all the `.then` methods until you supply an error handler.

```
var p2 = p1.then ( function checkTokenOnline (response) {
             if ( isBadFn(response) {
                 throw error;
             } else {
                 return nextData;
             }
   }) .then ( someFn 
    ) .then ( someOtherFn
    ) .catch ( function (error) {
          // someFn and someOtherFn skipped
          //log error
          throw error;
   });

 //return for further chaining
 return p2;
```

> 2) How can I set some of them parallel and some of them serial ?

To make two functions run in parallel, make two promises. Use `$q.all` to wait for them both to complete.

```
var p1 = $q.when ( fn1() );
var p2 = $q.when ( fn2() );

var p3 = $q.all ( [p1, p2] );

var p4 = p3.then ( function (responseList) {
      var response1 = responseList[0];
      var response2 = responseList[1];
      return something;
}). catch ( function (error) {
      //log error
      throw error;
});

//return for further chaining
return p4;
```

Be aware that `$q.all` is not **resilient**. If any promise throws an error, the `.then` method will be skipped and only the first error will go to the `.catch` method.

The rule of thumb for functional programming is **always return something**.

---

### Useful links

- [AngularJS $q Reference - Chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).
- [Ninja Squad -- Traps, anti-patterns and tips about AngularJS promises](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/)

Comment: Is .then() alwas available ? How is the correct syntax? `return` stands all alone in the code and it is not within curly brackets? Somehow irritating for PHP Programmers.

Comment: @georgeawg would you answer the question from Lonely Programmer ? That's good question, I think.. Thank you very much..

Comment: @LonelyProgrammer `.then` is a standard method for JavaScript promises . See the [Promises/A+ Open Standard](https://promisesaplus.com/). Or specifically for AngularJS the [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: @LonelyProgrammer AngularJS services that return promises include `$q.when`, `$http`, `$timeout`, `$interval`, all `.then` and `.catch` methods, many AngularJS custom modules and factory services and others.