# How to trigger a promise and then a second one with $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using `$q` in a method to get an array of objects. I also have a method called `getItems` which makes use of this promise (`all`).

I use `all` a second time at the bottom, to do stuff with `$scope.list`. The code has to be wrapped inside `all().then(function() { ... }` so it only triggers when `$scope.list` ready.

```
var all = function() { return $q.all([service.getAllItems()]) }

var getItems = function() {
  all().then(function(value) {
     $scope.list = JSON.parse(value)
  }, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason
  })
}

getItems()

all().then(function() {
  // do stuff with $scope.list
}
```

This works...almost. Sometimes the first `all` finishes first and sometimes the second one. So sometimes `$scope.list` has the objects and sometimes it's empty.

How to create a new promise that only triggers when `all` fetches the array of objects?

Comment: One can **return** the promise to **chain** from it. Remember the rule of thumb for functional programming is **always return something**.

Comment: Look at this question for more [Angular execution order with `$q`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q/34326388#34326388).

Comment: @georgeawg So functioning programming is the ideal way to program?

Comment: AngularJS, Q promises, and Javascript itself are taking ideas (and benefiting) from functional programming concepts. If you want to know more, ask that as a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
var all = function() { return $q.all([service.getAllItems()]) }

var getItems = function() {
  return all().then(function(value) {
     $scope.list = JSON.parse(value)
  }, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason
  });
}

getItems().then(function() {
  // do stuff with $scope.list
}
```

If you return a promise in a function you can chain a `.then` to it, so now your `getItems` will return the promise from `all()`, once this is fulfilled your code will continue

Comment: @Hey it worked. Thanks! I'm just learning about promises. They are convenient but a bit hard to understand.

Comment: No problem, just see it like this, as long as a function returns a promise you can chain a `.then` to it, when it returns a non-promise (result) your promise chain will be broken.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Dang! Not enough reputation to upvote comments.