# How to use $http promise response outside success handler

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

```
$scope.tempObject = {};

 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/myRestUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   $scope.tempObject = response
   console.log("Temp Object in successCallback ", $scope.tempObject);
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
console.log("Temp Object outside $http ", $scope.tempObject);
```

I am getting response in `successCallback` but
not getting `$scope.tempObject` outside `$http`. its showing `undefined`.

How to access `response` or `$scope.tempObject` after `$http`

Comment: $http get is an async call. The time your console.log outside the success callback executes, success callback is not executed. That's why $scope.tempObject is undefined.

Comment: But if I want to use `$scope.tempObject` after callback so how can I use it. ?

Comment: I recommend to learn about Promises. This article will help you to understand how it's works - http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: You can do the stuff inside callback function. Why do you need $scope.tempObject outside?

Comment: @varun I have some data outside, so I want to use that data with success callback `response` outside this function

Comment: Could you put the some more code or create a fiddle? I am not clear with the actual problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if I want to use $scope.tempObject after callback so how can I use it. ?

You need to **chain** from the httpPromise. Save the httpPromise and **return** the value to the onFullfilled handler function.

```
//save httpPromise for chaining
var httpPromise = $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/myRestUrl'
}).then(function onFulfilledHandler(response) {

   $scope.tempObject = response

   console.log("Temp Object in successCallback ", $scope.tempObject);

   //return object for chaining
   return $scope.tempObject;

});
```

Then outside you **chain** from the httpPromise.

```
httpPromise.then (function (tempObject) {
    console.log("Temp Object outside $http ", tempObject);
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

---

### Explaination of Promise-Based Asynchronous Operations

```
console.log("Part1");
console.log("Part2");
var promise = $http.get(url);
promise.then(function successHandler(response){
    console.log("Part3");
});
console.log("Part4");
```

[image: pic]

The console log for "Part4" doesn't have to wait for the data to come back from the server. It executes immediately after the XHR *starts*. The console log for "Part3" is inside a success handler function that is held by the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) and invoked *after* data has arrived from the server and the XHR *completes*.

#### Demo

```js
console.log("Part 1");
console.log("Part 2");
var promise = new Promise(r=>r());
promise.then(function() {
    console.log("Part 3");
});
console.log("Part *4*");
```

---

## Additional Resources

- [Angular execution order with `$q`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q)
- [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)
- [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)
- [How is javascript asynchronous AND single threaded?](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/03/14/wrapping-your-head-around-async-programming/)
- [Ninja Squad -- Traps, anti-patterns and tips about AngularJS promises](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/)
  Good theory but needs to be updated to use `.then` and `.catch` methods.
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Comment: `$q` helps me. I used `return $q(function ( resolve, reject ) { ... } )` then I resolve successCallback object. so its working

Comment: There is need to use `$q( (resolve,  reject) => {  } )` as the $http service already returns a promise. Doing so is error prone and considered an [anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: That means if we use `$timeout` function with some delay then also it will fetch complete data.for exmple - `$timeout(function () { console.log("Temp Object outside $http ", $scope.tempObject); }, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

$http call is async call. The callback function executes when it has returned a response. Meanwhile the rest of the function keeps executing and logs $scope.tempObject as {}.
When the $http is resolved then only $scope.tempObject is set.
Angular will bind the changed value automatically using two way binding.

{{tempObject}} in the view will update itself.

if you want to use tempObject after callback then do this

```
then(function(data){
   onSuccess(data);
},function(){

});

function onSuccess(data){
// do something
}
```

Comment: I am getting data in success callback, I want to use it after callback thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a $scope.$apply before to finish the successCallback function. An other solution is to change successCallback -> function so:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/myRestUrl' }).then(function(success) { $scope.tempObject = success; console.log("Temp Object in successCallback ", $scope.tempObject); }, function(error) { });
```

Comment: `$apply` is not helpful here. because its not the problem of any view or scope. problem is basically I want access of response outside

Comment: I used `$watch` in my success callback, but it does't reflect any value outside. and main thing is there is no need of watch because I am getting response properly

Comment: You try to set the success function similar my post?