# returning response from factory to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, response, factory, angular-promise

I'm currently using a factory to pass in a response to a controller. The issue that i am having...is that the response doesnt become defined until i press submit.

my factory (`responseHandler`):

```
return {
        setMessages: function(response) {
            if (response ===  undefined) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        }
    };
```

my controller:

```
$scope.messages = responseHandler.setMessages();
```

it works when i manually put a string into the setMessages function but doesnt work when i pass in a response. Any help would be great

thanks

EDIT:

in the response i am getting an array of just some string for ex..

```
[  
   {  
      "message":"Title required"
   },
   {  
      "message":"No first and last name"
   },
   {  
      "message":"No address info"
   },
   {  
      "message":"Cannot submit"
   }
]
```

Comment: How u passing response.Can u please share script

Comment: I am getting my response from a service that returns an array of strings. When i go to my dev console, i see that i am getting my responses returned into the factory...however i am not getting them passed to the controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use $http.successCallback response outside callback in angularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275451/how-to-use-http-successcallback-response-outside-callback-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to get as response.

You are calling a function that need a parameter **response**.

You have to provide this parameter in order to get a response.

It will not make sense since the same given parameter will be returned without any computation.

Comment: edited...my response just contains an array of strings that gets passed in the function i am calling the factory