# scope variable undefined outside `.then` method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, scope, angular-promise

I changed the scope variable in an if statement and outside the if statement it turned into an undefined variable

```
app.controller("Login", function($scope, $window,$http){
    var status;
    $scope.loginUser = function(logData){
        $http.post('/corporate/login',logData).then(function(response){
              var data = response.data
              var status = data.success;
              if(status == true){
                $scope.logStatus = true;
                console.log($scope.logStatus); // prints true
              }else{
                $scope.logStatus = false;
              }
        })

        console.log($scope.logStatus); //prints undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: The $http `.success` method is [deprecated and removed from AngularJs 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339?s=5|1.9570#35331339). Instead, use the standard promise `.then` and `.catch` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> outside ... it turned into an undefined variable

It did not "turn into" an `undefined` value. The last `console.log` in the code executes *before* the console.log in the success handler. It is `undefined` because it has not yet been set by the success handler.

---

### Expaination of Promise-Based Asynchronous Operations

```
console.log("Part1");
console.log("Part2");
var promise = $http.get(url);
promise.then(function successHandler(response){
    console.log("Part3");
});
console.log("Part4");
```

[image: pic]

The console log for "Part4" doesn't have to wait for the data to come back from the server. It executes immediately after the XHR *starts*. The console log for "Part3" is inside a success handler function that is held by the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) and invoked *after* data has arrived from the server and the XHR *completes*.

For more information, see [How to use $http promise response outside success handler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280444/5535245)

#### Demo

```js
console.log("Part 1");
console.log("Part 2");
var promise = new Promise(r=>r());
promise.then(function() {
    console.log("Part 3");
});
console.log("Part *4*");
```

Comment: Does this mean that if I define a variable inside the "then()" block, I am only able to reference that variable from within that block as well? For instance, will this work?: 
`var promise = $http.get(url);
promise.then(function successHandler(response){
    $scope.x = yz;
}); 
console.log($scope.x)`

Answer (score 0):

`$http` is asynchronous. Your `if/else` conditions are in the success callback. Problem is that the `console.log($scope.logStatus);` line is called before the success callback gets called

You should probably initialise `$scope.logStatus = false` before the `$http` call.

EDIT:

If like you said, `$scope.logStatus` remains false, then check if your if block is being called. See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/51bsbzL0/253/

Comment: that way it will remain false although the if statement changed it to true

Comment: Just write `$scope.logStatus = false` before the `$http` call, your logic will work fine!

Comment: I just did and it remained false

Comment: I'm sure the if is the one executed not the else. The asynchronous callback does not update the scope variable I'm sure that's what's going on but I can't find a solution

Comment: Did you see the fiddle I posted? it certainly updates the logStatus. Do you get the console.log in the if block? Only thing different from your code and that in the fiddle is the endpoint. Confirm if some other code isn't overwriting logStatus

Comment: nothing is overriding the logStatus at all, I see that your fiddle works but what I noticed is that you can't override the logStatus after the callback

Comment: @MahmoudYoussef: You DO realize that everything inside `$http.post` will happen AFTER, the `$scope.loginUser` function have returned? Therefore the last `console.log` outside the `.post()` will print first.

Comment: I also found out that it works on the html but doesn't work in the console.log