# Angular Asynchronous Data to scope and use it in view file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am using `Angular 1.5`
I want to load data from server and store it to scope and use it in view file.

My data is stored in the scope after load the view file. How can I store data to scope first and than load the view file so that I can use scope data in view file.

Here is my code

```
$scope.getProfile = function() {
        Account.getProfile()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.user = response.data;
                console.log($scope.user); //here data printed in console
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data.message, response.status);
            });
    };

if($auth.isAuthenticated()){
    $scope.getProfile();
    console.log($scope.user)//here data not print in console.
}
```

Comment: Its because of Asyc calls!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I know that. But I am new to `angularjs`. How can I solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Read the duplicate so you understand how asynchronous calls work in javascript and how to use them. In your case the call `getProfile` returns immediately but the request has gone to the server to do work. The next line will not yet have the result until that call completes. This call is known as a promise.

Comment: `But I am new to angularjs. How can I solve it` <= this is nothing specific to angularjs, its a core concept to using javascript and any type of external I/O communication from javascript (like calling a method on a remote server).

Answer (score 1):

Code in `.then` blocks execute asynchronously *after* the function returns.

Have the function return a promise for the value and extract that value in a `.then` block:

```
$scope.getProfile = function() {
    return Account.getProfile()
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
        console.log($scope.user); //here data printed in console
        return $scope.user;
    })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.message, response.status);
        throw response;
    });
};

if($auth.isAuthenticated()){
    var promise = $scope.getProfile();
    promise.then(function(user) {
        console.log(user);
    });
};
```

By using a promise returned by the function, a `.then` block can be created that will execute after the data has returned from the server.

---

### Explaination of Promise-Based Asynchronous Operations

```
console.log("Part1");
console.log("Part2");
var promise = $http.get(url);
promise.then(function successHandler(response){
    console.log("Part3");
});
console.log("Part4");
```

[image: pic]

The console log for "Part4" doesn't have to wait for the data to come back from the server. It executes immediately after the XHR *starts*. The console log for "Part3" is inside a success handler function that is held by the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) and invoked *after* data has arrived from the server and the XHR *completes*.

For more information, see [How to use $http promise response outside success handler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280444/5535245)

---

#### Demo

```js
console.log("Part 1");
console.log("Part 2");
var promise = new Promise(r=>r());
promise.then(function() {
    console.log("Part 3");
});
console.log("Part *4*");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the Async behavior, you might need to use the callbacks. Give this a try

```
$scope.getProfile = function(callback) { //added callback function
  Account.getProfile()
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
      callback($scope.user); //callback execution
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.message, response.status);
    });
};
```

And your caller should be like following:

```
if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
  $scope.getProfile(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
  });
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: when I console `$scope.user` outside of function than it returns undefined. In view file I can not print `user` data

Comment: Some people consider putting a callback-based wrapper around a promise-based API an anti-pattern. See [Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code every time an angular page loads, you could make use of ‘resolve’, as long as ‘UI-Router’ setup.

If you just want to execute some code without loading data, you are better off using ‘**$viewContentLoading**‘ or ‘**$viewContentLoaded**‘. Please note the following documentation.

You can refer [here](https://azizsaboor.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/angularjs-event-to-call-after-loading/) for more information

Answer (score -1):

change your code as shown below:

```
    $scope.getProfile = function() {
        Account.getProfile()
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $scope.user = response.data;
                        console.log($scope.user); //here data printed in console
                        if($auth.isAuthenticated()){
                           console.log($scope.user)//here data not print in console.
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data.message, response.status);
                    });
    };

$scope.getProfile();
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: This does not translate into what was posted in the OP. This could result in a `StackoverflowException` as it could recurs infinity.

Comment: Oops! Missed calling function to leave outside, now code edited.

Comment: No, the logic is still not right. I formatted the OPs code (no other changes, just indentation). Look again and see if you can spot the intent.