# Dynamic $http GET method to assign multiple variables different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Im trying to create a get function that will have a dynamic URL for variables needed from an api. I am assigning the $scope variable to the returned data however I cannot access it. I console log the variable and it returns undefined. Below is my code.

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http) {

  var getRequest = function (url) {
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: url
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }),
        function error(err) {
            console.log("This ain't working..." + err);
        }
}

$scope.firstURL = getRequest('https://url1');
$scope.secondURL = getRequest('https://url2');
```

Comment: Add this line $scope.firstURL = response; inside your .then call back function.

Comment: @Thangadurai then id need to have multiple get requests for each variable.  I would need a second get request with $scope.secondURL = response. Im trying to just reuse one get request for multiple variables.

Comment: @William.Doyle Then move this to a service/factory layer and use it as needed. I have an example below, app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  return {
    async: function() {
      return $http.get('test.json');  //1. this returns promise
    }
  };
});

Comment: You're returning the entire $http response; you probably want `response.data`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use $http promise response outside success handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275451/how-to-use-http-promise-response-outside-success-handler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getRequest` has no `return` statement, this is why it returns `undefined`. Also, `then` callbacks are invoked asynchronously. If you would like to assign server responses to $scope vars, you should do this inside of then callback:

```
var getRequest = function (url) {
    return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url: url
        });
}

getRequest('https://url1').then(function (response) {
    $scope.firstURL = response;
}));
getRequest('https://url2').then(function (response) {
    $scope.secondUrl = response;
}));
```

Comment: Thank you Kind stranger, that is exactly what I was getting wrong. asynchronous promises stuff is kind of hard to understand but thank you for the help

Comment: Could this be used for a POST and PUT request as well?

Comment: Yes, sure; this should be valid for all promises. Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: For the PUT and POST request how would I know that the request has been successful? Currently im getting an error "Cannot read property 'then" when using the post method         


postRequest('url',data).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

Comment: @William.Doyle Make sure you return `$http(...)` in `postRequest` function, not just execute it. In case it does not help, please show me the `postRequest`. If request succeeds, a success callback (1st one in `then(...)`) will be invoked. Otherwise an error callback (2nd one) will be invoked.

Comment: This is the post request: 
    var postRequest = function (url, data) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data:data,
            url: url
        });
    }

Comment: @William.Doyle , you should **return** $http(...) in postRequest: `var postRequest = function (url, data) { return $http({ method: 'POST', data:data, url: url }); `. Otherwise it is the same to `return undefined;` in the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this Js Bin](https://jsbin.com/gumapohozu/edit?html,js,console) you can achieve what you need with the following.

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$http', '$log'];

function MyController($http, $log){

  var vm = this;

  vm.nick1 = 'AndreaM16';
  vm.nick2 = 'Aspha9';
  vm.gitUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users';

  vm.data1 = '';
  vm.data2 = '';

  getSomeData(vm.gitUrl + '/' + vm.nick1).then(function(res){
    vm.data1 = res.data;
    $log.log(vm.data1);
  });

  getSomeData(vm.gitUrl + '/' + vm.nick2).then(function(res){
    vm.data1 = res.data;
    $log.log(vm.data2);
  });

  function getSomeData(url){
    return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url
    });
  }


}
```

As @Alina Loi Said, the asynchronous nature of the call forces you to get the response using `.then()`.