# How to chain promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a question regarding chaining promise.

Here's my code:

```
var removeProducts = function(id) {
    anotherService.removeProducts(id); // this will return a promise.
}

var addProduct = function(id) {
    myService.addProduct({id: id})
}

$scope.pickProduct = function() {
    myService.updateId({'id':123}).$promise.then(function(items) {
        items.categories.filter(function(category) {
            if (category.type === 'NEW') {
               removeProducts(items.id);
            }
        })
        //this is the part I don't know how to proceed. I need to make sure 
        //the product is removed before first and update ID second so I can add     
        //another product.  

        addProduct(item.id);
    })
}
```

Basically I need to call the `updateId` method from `myService` every time I add or remove a product. So the steps are as follows:

```
Update ID
Remove product if there is a type 'New'
Update ID 
Add product
```

How do I change this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the statement `addProduct(item.id)`, from where do you get `item`? Or is that a typo?

Comment: For information on chaining promises, see [Angular execution order with `$q`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q/34326388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can chain promise like that:

```
myService.pickProduct(product)
    .then(_update)
    .then(_remove)
    .then(_add)
    .catch(..);



function _update(product) {
    return product.id;
}

function _remove(id) {
   return new Date();
}

function _add(date) {

}
```

The return value of a `then` will be the input of the next 'chain' promise `then`. In my case the service function `pickProduct`has to return a promise that holds the product,  because I expect it as input within `_update`and so on.

Comment: is there anyway I can pass an additional param that didn't return from the previous promise like function _remove(id, data) in your case? +1

Comment: Hmm. You could use a closure for that and put the _update function into the function where your desired input lives and then just access it or pull the param through all method call as an input and return an array within the promise handlers..

Answer (score 1):

call the updateID function in the then returned from the removeProduct. Like this:

```
$scope.pickProduct = function() {
  myService.updateId({
    'id': 123
  }).$promise.then(function(items) {
    items.categories.filter(function(category) {
      if (category.type === 'NEW') {
        removeProducts(items.id).then(function() {
            //call updateId .then(function(){
            // call add product
          }
        };
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I can make this better without adding so many nested then(function() ?  +1