# Promise chaining when using $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to understand the promise API and chaining, particularly the timing when `$timeout`is used with `.then()`. What I had expected from the following is that since `$timeout` returns a promise, `.then()` would not be called until it had resolved.

But instead of ABAB, it's ABBA all the time.

How can I use the promise API to ensure that a long-running call (or delayed call using `$timeout`) is actually complete before the `.then()` gets executed?

**Code**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ThenCtrl', ThenCtrl);

function ThenCtrl($timeout, $q) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.items = [];

  $q.when(pushA()).then(pushB());

  $timeout(pushA, 5000).then(pushB());

  function pushA() {
    vm.items.push('A');
  }

  function pushB() {
    vm.items.push('B');
  }
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ThenCtrl as vm">
    {{vm.items}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I've set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kan3c61t/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't invoke the functions inside the `.then` methods.

```
  ̶$̶q̶.̶w̶h̶e̶n̶(̶p̶u̶s̶h̶A̶(̶)̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶p̶u̶s̶h̶B̶(̶)̶)̶;̶
  $q.when(pushA()).then(pushB);

  ̶$̶t̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶(̶p̶u̶s̶h̶A̶,̶ ̶5̶0̶0̶0̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶p̶u̶s̶h̶B̶(̶)̶)̶;̶    
  $timeout(pushA, 5000).then(pushB);
```

Instead pass the functions as arguments to the `.then` method. The `$q` service will hold those functions to be invoked later.

The way the `$q` service works is it stores the argument of the `.then` method as a function to be invoked later. In this case, the `$q` service was storing the value returned by `pushB()` with the side effect of pushing `B` immediately onto the array.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xvLpmb4/)

Comment: This is a pretty interesting solution too.

Comment: Very clearly stated. What a difference those parenthetical pairs can make.

Comment: This helped me tremendously

Comment: What about functions with multiple arguments?

Comment: Clear. But I need to call a function `function1` and then call another function `function2` once the `function1` is resolved because I need the result of the `function1`. But `function2` also has some other additional arguments that are available in the .js file.... Probably I need to also send these values to function1 and make function1 return a result which has these variables as well which can then be used in function2?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Please ask that as a new question. The comment section should only be used to clarify the existing anwser. Lengthy discussions are not appropriate here. Also look at [AngularJS execution order with `$q` — Chaining Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245)

Answer (score 6):

Here you go.
What I did is essentially added a `success` function in the `then` part of the code.

```
$timeout(pushA, 5000).then(function(success) {
    pushB()
  });
```

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kan3c61t/1/).

You can also add an `error function` like this

```
 $timeout(pushA, 5000).then(function(success) {
    pushB()
  },function(error){console.log("Error");});
```

While searching for this answer, I also came across this very [helpful link](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Comment: This is an excellent reminder of the underlying API structure; thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned - your bigger issue is that you `.then(promise)` and not `.then(function)`.

Promises represent a value + time. It's the **result of an already started operation**. A promise is a value - `then` waits for *functions*. You can't "run a promise after another promise" - since a promise means the operation has already started.

When you `then(x)` for anything other than a *function* it is ignored. This is an unfortunate choice in the promises spec but we have to live with it.

Since your calls are synchronous you should not use promises for it. If your code does something synchronous you can sequence actions with `;` and not `then`:

```
pushA();
pushB();
```

If it's a call that returns promises then it just becomes:

```
pushA().then(pushB);
```

There is no point in calling `$q.when` which converts non-promises to promises.

I'd write it as:

```
pushA();
$timeout(5000).then(pushB);
```

There is no point to convert the first synchronous action to a promise returning function or to involve promises anywhere except the timeout. If you need `pushA` to happen after 5000ms itself I'd still probably write:

```
$timeout(5000).then(pushA).then(pushB)
```

Since I think it is more readable and again we don't involve `pushA` and `pushB` with promises directly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's sometimes very difficult to capture intent well while being both brief and clear for SO posts. What I was trying to capture is a scenario where we intend A to be resolved before B, and A is the promise that must carry the delay. Meaning: I would like `pushA` to complete it's work, including the delay, and then-and-only-then execute `pushB`. Here's an updated fiddle, implemented with your input, which helped me arrive at what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/nam3cbaw/1/