# How to pass currently signed in user id to resolve block in ui-router state? (AngularJS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the currently signed-in user to the resolve block of a 'user' state (I'm using ui-router), so upon sign-in, user will be in url of .../users/:id.

Other routes are nested inside :user route, so this seems the most logical path to me (I may be wrong).

I'm using angular_devise here so i should be able to extract the :id from from API via Auth, but I'm running into some trouble.

(Included other possible relevant files below.)

**App.js**

```
$stateProvder
  .state('users', { 
      url: '/users/{id}', 
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
          userPromise: ['$stateParams', 'users', 'Auth', function($stateParams, users, Auth) {
            return users.get(
                Auth.currentUser().then(function (user) {
                return user.id;
            })
          );
      }]
    }
  })
```

**Users.js**

```
.factory('users', ['$http', function($http) {
    var u = {
        userArray: []
    };
    u.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/users/' + id + '.json').then(function(res) {
            console.log('request: ', res.data);
            angular.copy(res.data, u.userArray);

        });
    };
    return u;
}]);
```

**Users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        authorize @user
        respond_with @user
    end
end
```

**NavCtrl.js**

```
.controller('NavCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'Auth',
    function($scope, Auth) {
        $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
        $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

        Auth.currentUser().then(function (user) {
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function (e, user) {
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:login', function (e, user) {
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:logout', function (e, user) {
            $scope.user = {};
        });
    }])
;
```

FYI. $http request is being sent to a rails backend.

I would be very grateful if anyone can advise what i might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be very grateful if anyone can advise what i might be doing wrong.

If we restate your code:

```
$stateProvder
  .state('users', { 
      url: '/users/{id}', 
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
          userPromise: ['$stateParams', 'users', 'Auth', function($stateParams, users, Auth) {
            var derivePromise = Auth.currentUser()
               .then(function (user) {
                    return user.id;
            });
            //WRONG - user.get does not accept promises
            return users.get(derivedPromise);
      }]
    }
  })
```

You can see that `Auth.currentUser().then(fn)` returns a derived promise and that the `users.get` function does not accept promises.

---

> For future reference, how would i know this is actually a derived promise and not a number ?

Any object that has a `.then` method returns a derived promise. This is as specified by [Promises/A+  open standard for interoperable JavaScript promises](https://promisesaplus.com/).

AngularJS uses the [$q Service Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

> ### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.

Think of promises as a container for a value that will be returned *in the future.* That value can only be retrieved by registering functions (using the `.then` or `.catch` methods) with the `$q` service. The `$q` service holds those functions and invokes them when the promise is resolved either fulfilled or rejected. Those methods can also be used to retrieve results *after* the promise has resolved.

The `$q` service supports supports passing promises as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures.

In summary, **returning** a value to a `.then` method creates a new derived promise suitable for **chaining**. It will **never** return a value.

For more information, see [Angular execution order with `$q`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q).

Comment: If i check `typeof()` for `console.log` output, it returns `number` for `Auth.currentUser().then(function (user) { console.log( typeof( user.id) );});`. For future reference, how would i know this is actually a `derived promise` and not a `number` ?

Comment: Does that mean the only way to get a value out of a promise is to assign it to a variable like, `.then(function(user) { $scope.user_id = user.id })` ?

Comment: The `$stateProvider` resolver accepts promises. Give it a derived promise chained from the  `user.id` promise..