# Synchronously using forEach with $q

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous

So I have a situation where I need to build an Object, then inject some items into that Object, and then make an API call and also inject the API's response into that Object. It's a complex Object so we'll just assume that's alright, but anyway, I think that I need to do these 3 things synchronously and using `array.forEach` means they run asynchronously.

I hope my example is simple enough to understand, but basically I do 3 things:

- Create an empty Array of Classes/Classrooms
- Loop through an Array of Class IDs and create an Object for each `Class`
- Loop through an Array of `Students` and push them into a `students` Array inside the `Class` Object
- Loop through an Array of `Options` and push them into an `options` array inside the `Class` Object

Finally, I have something that could look like this for each Class:

```
{
  class_id: "abc123",
  students: [{}, {}, {}],
  options: [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

And finally, here is my code:

```
// Create Array of Class Objects
var classes = [];

function processArray(array, func) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    array.forEach(function(item, index) {
      func(item);
      if (index === (array.length - 1)) resolve();
    })
  })
}

// Create Courier Objects
processArray(classIds, function(id) {
  classes.push({class_id: id, students: [], options: []});
}).then(function(response) {
  // Inject Students into each Class
  processArray(students, function(students) {
    _.find(classes, {'class_id': student.class_id}).students.push(student);
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Inject classOptions into each Class
    processArray(classOptions, function(classOption) {
      _.find(classes, {'class_id': classOption.class_id}).classOptions.push(classOption);
    }).then(function(response) {
      // Print the classes
      console.log(classes);
    })
  })
});
```

I've create a function which does it synchronously but I'd like to know if anyone can think of a much, much cleaner and more efficient way of doing the above. It seems extremely hacky, and maybe I don't even need to do it synchronously if I arranged my functions correctly.

Comment: Just chain the promises together.  If they need to be synchronous, then what you have works fine.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Am I right in assuming that chaining the promises would result in something like `function1().then(function2().then(function3().then('done')))`?

Comment: Promises return promises when [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) resolves, so you can just do `promise1.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)`

Comment: @ryanyuyu Makes sense, so I'd basically be removing the `function(response) {}` part from my `.then()`s above in this case and just doing `processArray().then(processArray())`. Would save a bit of code.

Comment: Yeah and make it more readable.  I don't really know anything simpler than this for chaining promises.

Answer (score 1):

you are using nested promises. These suck. One major advantage of promises is to avoid the 'callback nightmare' of deep nesting.

Use this syntax ...

```
promise1.then(function(response1) {
  // do something with response 1 (and possibly create promise2 here based on response1 if required)
  return promise2
}).then(function(response2) {
  // do something with response 2
  return promise3
}).then(function(response3) {
  // do something with response 3
  // do something with promise 3???
}).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    // will trigger this on a failure in any of the above blocks
    // do something with error Response
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Working with Promise Based APIs that Return Arrays

The `processArray` function returns a promise that resolves to null.

```
//WRONG
//Returns a promise that resolves to null
//
function processArray(array, func) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    array.forEach(function(item, index) {
      func(item);
      if (index === (array.length - 1)) resolve();
    })
  })
}
```

To return a promise that resolves to an array, use `$q.all`.

```
//RIGHT
//Returns a promise that resolves to an array
//
function processArray(array, func) {
    var promiseArray = [];
    array.forEach(function(item, index) {
        promiseArray.push($q.when(func(item));
    });
    return $q.all(promiseArray);
}
```

In either case whether `func(item)` returns either a value or a promise, `$q.when` will return a promise.

Be aware that `$q.all` is **not resilient**. It will resolve fulfilled with an array of values or it will resolve rejected with the first error.

```
processArray(array, func)
    .then( function onFulfilled(dataList) {
        //resolves with an array
        $scope.dataList = dataList;
    }).catch( function onRejected(firstError) {
        console.log(firstError);
    });
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I right in assuming that the `.catch()` can also come after several chained `.then()`s as well? To make sure I don't have to do `.then().catch().then().catch()....`

Comment: Yes, when a promise resolves rejected, all the subsequent `.then` functions in the chain get skipped until the next `.catch`. Just like `try` `catch` blocks in synchronous code. For more information on chaining promises, see [Angular execution order with `$q`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q).