# Angular $http promise always resolving

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, interceptor, angular-promise

In every $http call with `.then(successFunc)` and `.catch(errFunc)` (alternatively `then(successFunc, errFunc)` the `then`/`success` is always called (the promise is successfully resolved).

Example

```js
$http.get('/some/resource') 
//   /some/resource --> HTTP 400
    .then(function(response)
    {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(function(reason)
    {
        console.log('error');
    })

// Console: 
// - success
```

Is this the intended behaviour or what causes this?

Comment: This is not the default behaviour, but might be due to a response interceptor you have used in your application. Usually the response interceptors are global and you might not be aware of it's presence if it is a large application. Could you isolate this code in a fiddle to reproduce the same issue?

Comment: I created this as self-answered Q&A question to keep it around for other people since there was no similar question here on SO. You describe exactly the issue I wanted to point out with this post (also see my in-depth answer). Still thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not intended behaviour. Normally it should call `.then()` on `HTTP 2xx` and `.catch()` on `HTTP 4xx` and `HTTP 5xx` (not sure about the others).

The described behaviour is probably caused by another `.catch()` returning a resolved promise.

In a slightly changed example:

```js
//In some Service:
function getResources()
{
    $http.get('/some/resource') 
    //   /some/resource --> HTTP 400
        .then(function(response)
        {
            console.log('service success');
            return response;
        })
        .catch(function(reason)
        {
            console.log('service error');
            // IMPORTANT: although this is returned 
            // in a .catch() it returns a resolved promise
            return reason;
        });
}

//In some Controller:
someService.getResources()
    .then(function(response)
    {
        console.log('controller success');
    })
    .catch(function(reason)
    {
        console.log('controller error');
    });


// Console:
// - service error
// - controller success
```

Note that this can also be caused by a registered `http interceptor`:

```js
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q)
{
    return {
        'response': function(response)
        {
            // do something
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection)
        {
            // do something
            return rejection; // <-- this causes the problem
            // instead do
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example **converts** a rejection to a resolved promise.

```
$http.get('/some/resource') 
//   /some/resource --> HTTP 400
    .then(function(response)
    {
        console.log('success');
        //IMPORTANT -- return to chain data
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(reason)
    {
        console.log('error');
        //IMPORTANT -- throw to chain rejections
        throw reason;
    })
```

When a catch handler omits a `throw` statement, the function returns `undefined` which **converts** the rejection to a promise that resolves `undefined`.

Look in your code for a [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) that is following the same erroneous pattern.

The rule in functional programming is always `return` (or `throw`) something.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the `throw` keyword in use with promises. Do you have any example demonstrating the correct behaviour?

Comment: See [Angular execution order with `$q`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245)

Comment: I just tested it in a fiddle - works as described, however it still propagates the error to the browser, hence I would rather prefer `return $q.reject(reason)` over `throw reason` (see [Angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)).