# What is the usage of $q and promise when we need callback for several methods

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using angularJS and trying to creating amazon VPC through [aws.sdk.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html)

Now when I create VPC I have to done various configuration and call below methods in chain

1. create vpc `() => vpc_`
2. create internet gateway `() => igw_`
3. attach internet gateway `(vpc_, igw_) =>`
4. create subnet `(vpc_) => subnet_`
5. create route table `(vpc_) => rtb_`
6. associate route table `(rtb_, subnet_) =>`
7. create security group `(vpc_) => sg_`
8. add inbound rule `(sg_) =>`
9. additionally create tags for each generated resources .

as you can see some function parameter depends on previous function and so on. I am using $q services on each AWS method but this is became so large callback hell.

I also capture notifications of each function in back so my input function became like this

```
functionOne().then(function(res1) {
   console.info(res1);
   functionTwo(res1.id).then(res2) {
      console.info(res2);
       ......... series of functions within function....
        ----------------
        ----------------
        .then(res7) { functionEight(res7.id) {
        }, function (err) {}, function (notify) {})
        .finally(function(){ console.log('Finally done everything'); });
       ---------------------
       ---------------------
   }, function (err2) {
  console.error(err2);
  }, function (notify2) {
   console.log(nofify2);
  });
}, function (err1) {
  console.error(err1);
}, function (notify1) {
   console.log(nofify1);
});
```

my function signature is as below

```
 functionX: function() {
                    var d = $q.defer();
                    var params = {
                        //...
                    };
                    ec2.anyMethodName(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            d.reject(err);
                        } else {
                            d.notify('Notifications methods');
                            d.resolve(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return d.promise;
                }
```

You can see the chaining of methods in my controller  [here](http://pastebin.com/8bTVZk1P)

So my question is

- Does [Amazon native thenable promise](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) property can be used in angular? if yes then how do we implement notifications?
- Is there any sorter way to do that? like error will be captures in last? using `$.all()` but do not not how?
- If i use `.finally()` on functionOne than it throw error in console 
  ***.finally is not a function***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you

```
functionOne()
    .catch(errorHandlerOne)
    .then(functionTwo) // calls functionTwo(responseOne)
    .catch(errorHandlerTwo)
    .then(functionThree) // calls functionThree(responseTwo)
    .catch(errorHandlerThree)
    .finally(finalHandler)
```

**Edit:** If you want to access the result of `functionOne` in `functionThree`, you can do the following:

```
functionTwo(resultOne) {
    var promise = d.promise;
    promise.then(function(resultTwo) {
       return [resultOne, resultTwo];
    });
  return d.promise
}
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174520/1409180) answer for more details.

You don't need to necessarily have to write anonymous callbacks as promise resolve and reject handlers

Your callbacks will be called with the resolved/rejected promise from the previous function automatically.

#### If you want your *entire chain to fail if any one promise fails*, you call always use `.all()`, so that's something you should pay attention to if you want to use `.all()`.

Comment: and where do i get the notifications sent via `d.notify()` written inside each function?

Comment: see in my question? in method 3 I need parameter as the result of method 1 and method 2. as method 2 does not require any parameter .

Comment: Does 1.all also called in series or parallel? can you please highlight how to use `$.all`

Comment: When you chain promises in the fashion that I've mentioned, the result of previous promises will be passed as the argument to your current promise. `functionThree` will _by default_ be passed an argument which is the resolved result of `functionTwo` when it is called in this fashion. If `functionTwo` doesn't require an argument, then you don't need to implement it at all. Just ignore the param.

Comment: but `functionThree` requires params from the resolve of `functionOne` and `functionTwo`

Comment: When you pass in a group of arrays to `.all()`, it doesn't know anything about what order the functions need to be executed. So it happens in **parallel**. Promises are _triggered_ serially, but the results don't come in any particular order

Comment: So `.all` is probably not the solution for you

Comment: If you need to access the result of `functionOne` in `functionThree`, I guess you can assign the result of `functionOne` to a variable and access in `functionThree` but that seems to be a hack. I guess you could try adding a custom field to your promise when calling it i.e. in `functionTwo`, before `return promiseThree`, just add a `promiseThree.tempData = functionOneResponse` and try and access this object in `functionThree`. I'm not sure about this though. Never tried it. I'll look around for an answer for that question.

Comment: Thanks @nikjohn ; i will surely look into the way you suggest. let me try

Comment: @pro.mean I've made an edit to the answer  with your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126322/discussion-between-pro-mean-and-nikjohn).

Answer (score 1):

To chain promises, `return` values to the success handlers; `throw` values to the rejection handlers:

```
functionOne().then(function onSuccess(res1) {
    console.info(res1);
    //return promise to chain
    return functionTwo(res1.id);
}).catch(function onReject(error1) {
    console.log(error1)
    //throw to chain rejection
    throw error1;
}).then(function onSuccess2(res2) {
    console.info(res2);
    //return promise to chain
    return functionThree(res2.id);
}).then(function onSuccess3(res3) {
    console.info(res3);
    //return promise to chain
    return functionFour(res3.id);
}).then(function onSuccess4(res4) {
    console.info(res4);
    //return to chain
    return res4.id;
});
```

It is very important to `throw` to rejection handlers. If a rejection handler simply does a console log and omits the `throw` statement, the function returns `undefined` and the rejection gets **converted**. The next success handled will be invoked with `undefined` as its argument.

From the Docs:

> ### Chaining promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs

--[AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)

For more information, see [SO: Angular execution order with `$q` -- Chaining Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245)

---

> - Does [Amazon native thenable promise](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) property can be used in angular?

Promises from an external source such as the AWS API can be converted to a $q service with `$q.when`.

```
var angularPromise = $q.when(AWS.request.promise());
```

From the DOCS:

> ### when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

--[AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

Comment: why you have used .catch only once? what if there is any error in `functionSix()`

Comment: Put a `.catch` at the end of the chain and it will catch all of the previous errors. There is no need to include a rejection handler for every item in the chain. When a promise is rejected, all the subsequent success handlers are skipped. BUT if you have a rejection handler in the middle of the chain, it is very important to include a `throw` statement.