# How to access results of a promise at a later part of a chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, chaining

I have a promise chain like so

```
functionOne()
.catch(errorHandlerOne)
.then(functionTwo)        // calls functionTwo(responseOne)
.catch(errorHandlerTwo)
.then(functionThree)      // calls functionThree(responseTwo)
.catch(errorHandlerThree)
.finally(finalHandler)
```

This might seem to be an obvious answer, but my question is this:

**I can access the `responseOne` in `functionTwo()` fine, but how can I access the `responseOne` in `functionThree()` or `finalHandler()`?**

**Edit:** I thought about assigning it to a variable and accessing it later, but it seems to be quite hacky and against the flow of the promise chain. I'm looking for a better way

Comment: how about assigning it to a variable?

Comment: I should've added that to my question. I thought of doing that, but it seems to be quite hacky and against the flow of the promise chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I access the responseOne in functionThree() or finalHandler()?

By passing them forward in some way, as the return value of the `then` callback (or the resolution value of a promise it returns, which is effectively the same thing).

Example:

```js
function asyncOp(name) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(name);
  });
}
asyncOp("one")
  .then(result1 => {
    return asyncOp("two")
      .then(result2 => [result1, result2]);
  })
  .then(results => {
    console.log("results", results);
  });
```

An array like that is just one option; you could use an object, you could store the interim results in variables the handler close over, ...

Same example in ES5 (just in case someone needs it):

```js
function asyncOp(name) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(name);
  });
}
asyncOp("one")
  .then(function(result1) {
    return asyncOp("two")
      .then(function(result2) {
        return [result1, result2];
      });
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    console.log("results", results);
  });
```

Comment: My understanding is that the return value needs to be a promise in order for the chain to work properly. How can I make this work?

Comment: @nikjohn: No, it doesn't. If you return a non-"thenable" value from a `then` or `catch` callback, it's the same as returning a promise that's already resolved with that value. E.g., `return 42;` and `return Promise.resolve(42);` effectively do the same thing.

Comment: Ah brilliant. This solves it!