# $routeProvider resolve is not getting object from promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, route-provider

I am having trouble trying to get an array of objects from a promise. I have two issues. First, when the `GetAccounts()` gets called in the `AccountService`, it returns 2 objects. In the resolve, when I check the variable result, it doesn't have the 2 objects. Second, when the controller gets instantiated, it gives me this error: **accounts is not defined**. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**AccountService.js**

```html
app.factory('AccountService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        GetAccounts: function () {
            return $http.get('api/Account/GetAccounts')
            .then(function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function error(response) {
                return console.log("Oops!");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**AdminController.js**

```html
app.component('admin', {
    templateUrl: 'Content/app/components/admin/Admin.html',
    bindings: {
        accounts: '<'
    },
    controller: function () {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }
})
```

**route.js**

```html
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin', {
        template: '<admin accounts="$resolve.GetAccounts"></admin>',
        resolve: {
            GetAccounts: ['AccountService', function (AccountService) {
                var result = AccountService.GetAccounts();

                return result;
            }]
        }
    })
}]);
```

Comment: have you actually created the API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with ngRoute injecting resolve services into component controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242296/issue-with-ngroute-injecting-resolve-services-into-component-controller).

Comment: Be aware that the `GetAccounts` function is **converting** the rejected promise to a successful promise. See [Angular execution order with $q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324153/angular-execution-order-with-q/34326388#34326388) – georgeawg

Comment: yes I have create the API that's why I am able to get the 2 objects @floor

Comment: @georgeawg yes that was my other post from my work account but for some reason, I am not able to get the objects. The only difference with my other post is that I used webpack and this one I am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to get it works.

AdminController.js

```
app.component('admin', {
    templateUrl: 'Content/app/components/admin/Admin.html',
    bindings: {
        accounts: '<'
    }    })
```

**route.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin', {
        template: 'template.html',
        resolve: {
            GetAccounts: ['AccountService', function (AccountService) {
                var result = AccountService.GetAccounts();

                return result;
            }]
        },
        controller:['$scope','GetAccounts',function($scope, GetAccounts){
           $scope.accounts = GetAccounts;
        }]
    })
}]);
```

template.html

```
<div>
<admin accounts="accounts"></admin>
</div>
```