# How to pass data from one asynchronous to another asynchronous function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

### How to pass global variable value from one function to another function in angular?

I have 2 global variables as:

```
$scope.genewtId = null;
$scope.data1 = null;
```

I have 2 angular functions which look as below:

```
$scope.getID = function() {
    Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        console.log($scope.genewtId);

    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });
};

$scope.getDetails = function() {
    Service2.getDetails($scope.genewtId).then(function(response){
        // here response is having an error
        $scope.data1 = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data1.toString());
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });
};
```

When I pass value of `$scope.genewtId` from one function to another function, I get an error

> message: "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null""

However, `console.log($scope.genewtId);` is returning a value `787651` which means it is not null.

Please suggest if it can be implemented using `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The promises from the two services need to be [chained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245)

Modify the first function to return a promise:

```
$scope.getID = function() {
    return Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        console.log($scope.genewtId);
        return response.data[0].Id;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Modify the second function to both return a promise and accept an argument:

```
$scope.getDetails = function(id) {
    var genewtID = id || $scope.genewtId;
    return Service2.getDetails(genewtId).then(function(response){
        $scope.data1 = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data1.toString());
        return response.data;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Then [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245) the two promises:

```
var promise = $scope.getId();

var promise2 = promise.then(function(id) {
                   return $scope.getDetails(id);
               });

var promise2.then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

By using the `.then` method of the `getId` promise, the code waits for the `id` value to arrive from the server before making the request to `getDetails`.

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is because of `asynchronous` call of `promises`. What's happening is that :

Somehow, you are calling `Service2.getDetails($scope.genewtId)` before the value of `$scope.genewtId` has been set after the promise completion of `Service1.getId("abc").then`, and so the value remains `null`

Try:

```
$scope.getID = function(isCalledAfterDetails) {
    Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        console.log($scope.genewtId);
        if(isCalledAfterDetails && $scope.genewtId !== null){
            $scope.getDetails();
        }

    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });
};

$scope.getDetails = function() {
    if($scope.genewtId === null){
        $scope.getID(true);
    }else{
        Service2.getDetails($scope.genewtId).then(function(response){
            // here response is having an error
            $scope.data1 = response.data;
            console.log($scope.data1.toString());
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });
    }

};
```

Even, if this approach works, I would strongly suggest you to implement the function calls in a better way because `$scope.getDetails()` is dependent on `$scope.getID()` for setting value of `$scope.genewtId`.

If you want suggestion on how to implement it, please update the question with the use case and some more code

### Update

```
$scope.getID = function() {
    Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        $scope.getDetails();
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};

$scope.getDetails = function() {
        Service2.getDetails($scope.genewtId).then(function(response){
            // here response is having an error
            $scope.data1 = response.data;
            console.log($scope.data1.toString());
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });        
};
```

### Using service

In **service.js**

```
getDetails = function(id){
    var deferred = $q.derfer();
    $http.get('/user/'+id).then(function(response){
        var newId = response.data[0].Id;
        $http.get('/user/details'+newId).then(function(details){
            deferred.resolve(details)
        })
    })      
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.getDetails = function() {
        MySvc.getDetails("abc").then(function(response){
            console.log(response) // your details here
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });        
};
```

Comment: Please suggest if it can be implemented using `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Comment: @meallhour : and how are these functions dependent ? 1. Do you want to call `getDetails` after you get the ID from `getID` ? 2. or can they exist in separate `controller` ? Using events means that they are dependent on each other and they exist in separate `controller`.  So, they have to notify each other about their changes

Comment: 1. Do you want to call getDetails after you get the ID from getID  `Yes this is true`

Comment: can they exist in separate controller ?  `They are existing in the same controller and not separate controler`

Comment: @meallhour Check my updated code. Call `getDetails()` after the `Service1.getId()` is resolved. You can also move both logic `getId` and `getDetails` in the same Service as well and provide a single response with `ID` and `DETAILS`

Comment: @meallhour added example to use service, Make sure u are injecting `$q` and `$http` in the factory

Comment: Avoid the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). As written, the case where the $http returns a rejected promise is handled incorrectly.

Comment: @georgeawg : I have nested `$http` , the example you have shared seems to be just for one `$http` call

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the exception is coming from the server side.

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

It is getting printed on the console due to `console.log(error.statusText);`

You need to verify the logic when the value is used in the API.