# How to make sure that the variable is not null while using promise chaining approach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angularjs-service

I am using `init` as follows

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.getAllDetails();
};

$scope.getAllDetails= function () {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "api/endpoint"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.processData();
        }, function myError(response) {
            console.log(response.statusText);
        }
    );
};

$scope.processData() = function() {
//Logic to calculate var1
// var1 is then passed to $scope.getID to make call to Service1.getId(var1)

}
```

I have my first function which returns a promise:

```
$scope.getID = function() {
    return Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
    // In above line. Instead of manually passing `abc` I want to 
    //pass it as variable var1  
    // The desired call should be as below. 
    //But var1 is having null here
  //return Service1.getId(var1).then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        console.log($scope.genewtId);
        return response.data[0].Id;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

The second function returns a promise and accept an argument:

```
$scope.getDetails = function(id) {
    var genewtID = id || $scope.genewtId;
    return Service2.getDetails(genewtId).then(function(response){
        $scope.data1 = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data1.toString());
        return response.data;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Then [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34326388/5535245) the two promises:

```
var promise = $scope.getId();

var promise2 = promise.then(function(id) {
                   return $scope.getDetails(id);
               });

var promise2.then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error);
});
```

Problem:
The problem I am facing is related to `var1` in `$scope.processData()`
The `var1` is always having `null` value within `$scope.getID`
the `var1` value is `undefined`

Comment: **Note:** the code in this question were take from [this answer - The promises from the two services need to be chained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56052614/5535245) to the OPs question from two days ago -- [How to pass data from one asynchronous to another asynchronous function in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051521/how-to-pass-data-from-one-asynchronous-to-another-asynchronous-function-in-angul)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be a problem with closures. A function will have access to the containing closures of the code where it was *defined*, not where it is *called*.

Is var1 truly `null`, or is it in fact `undefined`? If it's `undefined`, probably what you need to do is make getId take var1 as an *argument* instead of relying on pulling the reference from the containing closure (which will not work for the reason stated above). If it's truly `null`, then the problem probably lies in the code that calculates var1, which you've omitted.

EDIT: The `getID()` function would look very similar, but it would start like this:

```
$scope.getID = function(var1) {
```

Instead of this:

```
$scope.getID = function(var1) {
```

And to call it you would probably do something like this:

```
var var1 = somethingToGetTheValueOfVar1();
$scope.getID(var1);
```

Comment: the `var1` value is `undefined`

Comment: can you please suggest how the updated `getId` will look like?

Comment: Added to my original answer. Having getId take an argument, though, will mean you'll have to change how you chain your promises at the end. Let me know if I can offer some pointers on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am facing is related to `var1` in `$scope.processData()` The `var1` is always having `null` value within `$scope.getID` the `var1` value is `undefined`

Add `var1` as a parameter to the function definition:

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶I̶D̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
$scope.getID = function(var1) {
    //return Service1.getId("abc").then(function(response){
    // In above line. Instead of manually passing `abc` I want to 
    //pass it as variable var1  
    // The desired call should be as below. 
    //But var1 is having null here
    return Service1.getId(var1).then(function(response){
        $scope.genewtId = response.data[0].Id;
        console.log($scope.genewtId);
        return response.data[0].Id;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error.statusText);
        throw error;
    });
};
```

---

> I am trying to call the function as following but it is not working
>
> ```
> $scope.processData() = function() { ... $scope.getID(var1); }
> ```

The left-hand side of an [assignment statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) must be a variable or property accessor.

```
$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶D̶a̶t̶a̶(̶)̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶ ̶
$scope.processData = function(data) { 
    //... 
    var var1 //= something
    return $scope.getID(var1); 
}
```

Then be sure to chain properly:

```
$scope.getAllDetails= function () {
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "api/endpoint"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        return $scope.processData(data);
    }, function myError(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        //IMPORTANT RE-THROW error
        throw response;
    });
};
```

It is important to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) values to `.then` blocks. Otherwise the new promise will resolve as `undefined`.

Also it is important to [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) from `.catch` blocks. Otherwise the new promise will be **converted** from a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise.

For more information, see

- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Comment: I am trying to call the function as following but it is not working `$scope.processData() = function() {
...
$scope.getID(var1);

}`